# How to merge categories Categorical column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
Date        Open     High      Low     Close     Struct  Trend                                           
2000-12-31  1477.87  1553.10  1254.19  1320.28   ohlc     D
2001-12-31  1321.62  1383.37   944.07  1148.08   ohlc     D
2002-12-31  1148.08  1176.97   768.58   879.82   ohlc     D
2003-12-31   881.69  1112.52   788.90  1111.92   olhc     U
2004-12-31  1112.61  1217.33  1060.74  1211.92   olhc     U
2005-12-31  1213.43  1275.80  1136.22  1248.29   olhc     U
2006-12-31  1252.03  1431.81  1219.29  1418.30   olhc     U
2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc   U/D
2008-12-31  1468.36  1471.77   741.02   903.25   ohlc     D
2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc   U/D
2010-12-31  1115.10  1262.60  1010.91  1257.64   olhc     U
2011-12-31  1257.62  1370.58  1074.77  1257.60   ohlc     U
2012-12-31  1258.86  1474.51  1258.86  1426.19   olhc     U
2013-12-31  1426.19  1849.44  1426.19  1848.36   olhc     U
2014-12-31  1845.86  2093.55  1737.92  2058.90   olhc     U
2015-12-31  2058.90  2134.72  1867.01  2043.94   ohlc     U
2016-12-31  2038.20  2277.53  1810.10  2238.83   olhc     U
2017-12-31  2251.57  2694.97  2245.13  2673.61   olhc     U
2018-12-31  2683.73  2940.91  2346.58  2506.85   ohlc     U
```

Data has two categorical columns 'Struct' and 'Trend'.

I would like to group data by these two columns.

When I do like this:

```
groups = data.groupby(['Struct', 'Trend'])
```

pandas get possible 6 different combinations of 'Struct' and 'Trend':
[('ohlc', 'D'), ('ohlc', 'U'), ('ohlc', 'U/D'), ('olhc', 'D'), ('olhc', 'U'), ('olhc', 'U/D')]

**How to merge groups, where 'Trend' category has 'D' as a substring of value ???**

I expect only 4 groups::

1. ('ohlc', 'D') + ('ohlc', 'U/D') --> ('ohlc', 'D')
2. ('ohlc', 'U') + ('ohlc', 'U/D') --> ('ohlc', 'U')
3. ('olhc', 'D') + ('ohlc', 'U/D') --> ('olhc', 'D')
4. ('olhc', 'U') + ('ohlc', 'U/D') --> ('olhc', 'U')

Simply say, each group 'D' must include all data 'D' and 'U/D'. Each group 'U' must include data 'U' and 'U/D'

**Edited:**

Expected result for sample above:

```
Date        Open     High      Low     Close     Struct  Trend                                           
2003-12-31   881.69  1112.52   788.90  1111.92   olhc     U
2004-12-31  1112.61  1217.33  1060.74  1211.92   olhc     U
2005-12-31  1213.43  1275.80  1136.22  1248.29   olhc     U
2006-12-31  1252.03  1431.81  1219.29  1418.30   olhc     U
2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc   U/D
2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc   U/D
2010-12-31  1115.10  1262.60  1010.91  1257.64   olhc     U
2011-12-31  1257.62  1370.58  1074.77  1257.60   ohlc     U
2012-12-31  1258.86  1474.51  1258.86  1426.19   olhc     U
2013-12-31  1426.19  1849.44  1426.19  1848.36   olhc     U
2014-12-31  1845.86  2093.55  1737.92  2058.90   olhc     U
2015-12-31  2058.90  2134.72  1867.01  2043.94   ohlc     U
2016-12-31  2038.20  2277.53  1810.10  2238.83   olhc     U
2017-12-31  2251.57  2694.97  2245.13  2673.61   olhc     U
2018-12-31  2683.73  2940.91  2346.58  2506.85   ohlc     U



Date        Open     High      Low     Close     Struct  Trend                                           
2000-12-31  1477.87  1553.10  1254.19  1320.28   ohlc     D
2001-12-31  1321.62  1383.37   944.07  1148.08   ohlc     D
2002-12-31  1148.08  1176.97   768.58   879.82   ohlc     D
2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc   U/D
2008-12-31  1468.36  1471.77   741.02   903.25   ohlc     D
2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc   U/D
```

I am doing like this, but I get just dataframe and want groups:

```
trend_dtype = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=['D', 'U/D'], ordered=False)
data['Trend'] = data['Trend'].astype(trend_dtype)
print(data.dropna())
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you want the final dataset looks like?

Comment: aren't your desired groups 1/3 identical? as well as 2/4?

Comment: @BrianJoseph No, your misreading the text. `ohlc` and `olhc`

Comment: @Trenton_M, oh wow that's confusing thanks

Comment: It took me a couple of times to read it correctly as well.

Comment: I've edited the question. Yep, there are two 'Struct' : ohlc, olhc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolen indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
df.loc[['U' in key for key in df['Trend']]]
```

---

```
          Date     Open     High      Low    Close Struct Trend
3   2003-12-31   881.69  1112.52   788.90  1111.92   olhc     U
4   2004-12-31  1112.61  1217.33  1060.74  1211.92   olhc     U
5   2005-12-31  1213.43  1275.80  1136.22  1248.29   olhc     U
6   2006-12-31  1252.03  1431.81  1219.29  1418.30   olhc     U
7   2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc   U/D
9   2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc   U/D
10  2010-12-31  1115.10  1262.60  1010.91  1257.64   olhc     U
11  2011-12-31  1257.62  1370.58  1074.77  1257.60   ohlc     U
12  2012-12-31  1258.86  1474.51  1258.86  1426.19   olhc     U
13  2013-12-31  1426.19  1849.44  1426.19  1848.36   olhc     U
14  2014-12-31  1845.86  2093.55  1737.92  2058.90   olhc     U
15  2015-12-31  2058.90  2134.72  1867.01  2043.94   ohlc     U
16  2016-12-31  2038.20  2277.53  1810.10  2238.83   olhc     U
17  2017-12-31  2251.57  2694.97  2245.13  2673.61   olhc     U
18  2018-12-31  2683.73  2940.91  2346.58  2506.85   ohlc     U
```

---

```
df.loc[['D' in key for key in df['Trend']]]
```

---

```
             Date     Open     High      Low    Close Struct Trend
0  2000-12-31  1477.87  1553.10  1254.19  1320.28   ohlc     D
1  2001-12-31  1321.62  1383.37   944.07  1148.08   ohlc     D
2  2002-12-31  1148.08  1176.97   768.58   879.82   ohlc     D
7  2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc   U/D
8  2008-12-31  1468.36  1471.77   741.02   903.25   ohlc     D
9  2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc   U/D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view your problem as duplicate the rows where `Trend` is `U/D`. So here's an approach:

```
df = (df.iloc[:,:-1]
   .join(df.Trend.str.split('/', expand=True))
   .melt(id_vars=df.columns[:-1], value_name='Trend')
   .dropna()
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
)
```

And your df is:

```
          Date     Open     High      Low    Close Struct Trend
0   2000-12-31  1477.87  1553.10  1254.19  1320.28   ohlc     D
1   2001-12-31  1321.62  1383.37   944.07  1148.08   ohlc     D
2   2002-12-31  1148.08  1176.97   768.58   879.82   ohlc     D
3   2003-12-31   881.69  1112.52   788.90  1111.92   olhc     U
4   2004-12-31  1112.61  1217.33  1060.74  1211.92   olhc     U
5   2005-12-31  1213.43  1275.80  1136.22  1248.29   olhc     U
6   2006-12-31  1252.03  1431.81  1219.29  1418.30   olhc     U
7   2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc     U
8   2008-12-31  1468.36  1471.77   741.02   903.25   ohlc     D
9   2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc     U
10  2010-12-31  1115.10  1262.60  1010.91  1257.64   olhc     U
11  2011-12-31  1257.62  1370.58  1074.77  1257.60   ohlc     U
12  2012-12-31  1258.86  1474.51  1258.86  1426.19   olhc     U
13  2013-12-31  1426.19  1849.44  1426.19  1848.36   olhc     U
14  2014-12-31  1845.86  2093.55  1737.92  2058.90   olhc     U
15  2015-12-31  2058.90  2134.72  1867.01  2043.94   ohlc     U
16  2016-12-31  2038.20  2277.53  1810.10  2238.83   olhc     U
17  2017-12-31  2251.57  2694.97  2245.13  2673.61   olhc     U
18  2018-12-31  2683.73  2940.91  2346.58  2506.85   ohlc     U
26  2007-12-31  1418.03  1576.09  1364.14  1468.36   olhc     D
28  2009-12-31   903.25  1130.38   666.79  1115.10   olhc     D
```

Notice the lines `(7,26)` and `(9,28)`.